# Getting incorrect info while parsing webpage with beautifulsoup - is it my code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code to check a certain webpage for live updates (there is a section on the page where updates are posted regularly). However, the code does not reliably return the latest update - the first time I run it, it always returns the latest update. However, as it continues looping it will randomly decide that the second or third latest update is the most recent one.

I don't think it is the website being unreliable, as it is the same format on the webpage - just for some reason it is not returning the most recent `<p>` tag after the 'live updates text'.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from groupy.client import Client
import time

# URL of the webpage you want to check for updates
url = "https://www.israelnationalnews.com/news/378017"
updates_list = []

# Function to download the webpage content
def download_webpage(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for any HTTP errors
        return response.text
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

# Function to check for updates under '<strong>Live Updates:</strong>'
def check_for_alerts(html_content):
    if html_content:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
        live_updates_tag = soup.find('p', class_='', text='Live Updates:')
        
        if live_updates_tag:
            next_p_element = live_updates_tag.find_next('p')
            if next_p_element:
                print(f"\nUpdate found:\n{next_p_element.get_text(strip=True)}")
            else:
                print("No updates found under 'Live Updates:'")
        else:
            print("No 'Live Updates:' found on the webpage.")
    else:
        print("Webpage content not found.")
    
    update = next_p_element.get_text(strip=True)
    return update

def check_recent(update):
    if update in updates_list:
        print ("This latest update is not new.\n")
    elif update not in updates_list:
        updates_list.append(update)

        client = Client.from_token('I3TymkKoSXxNrg1vCpouYZb4HVH2LO3X54NPPptC')
        chat = client.groups.get('97129195')
        message = chat.post(text=f"Arutz Sheva update: {update}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        webpage_content = download_webpage(url)
        update = check_for_alerts(webpage_content)
        check_recent(update)

        time.sleep(10)
```

Sample output:

```
Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.

Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:00 p.m.The official death toll from the Hamas massacre was raised to at least 900.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.


Update found:
Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens of IAF aircraft have attacked in the last few hours and continue to attack many targets throughout the Rimal neighborhood in Gaza.
This latest update is not new.
```

I've tried different ways of parsing the html, but I always end up with the same problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, `check_for_alerts()` always returns `None`.  It has no way to return anything else.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @JohnGordon My bad, I saw that but forgot to edit it on the post (even though I changed it on the program). Though I still have the problem that it randomly selects the wrong 'update'.

Comment: The sample output is misleading, because `check_for_alerts()` always prints `next_p_element` without knowing if it is a **new** update.  It would be better if the update were printed in a context that knows if it is new or not, perhaps inside `check_recent()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon 'No new updates' means that this latest update is not new.

Comment: Also, when you say things like "forgot to edit it on the post (even though I changed it on the program", it makes it very hard to trust that you are actually posting the correct code.  It shouldn't even be **possible** to post the wrong code, because you should **always** cut-and-paste the exact code.  You should never hand-edit the code while you are posting it, because errors like this always creep in.

Comment: @JohnGordon After I posted it I noticed that, so I changed it.

Comment: I understand what "No new updates* is **supposed** to mean.  But the first two lines in your sample output are identical, so the same update is printing twice.  It would be nicer if that didn't happen.

Comment: @JohnGordon Also, I edited 'No new updates' to say 'This latest update is not new', which is a clearer way.

Comment: @JohnGordon The first time it prints it is a new update - the program has not seen it before. It is not printing twice, the first time it is new, the second time it is old.

Comment: You're using `requests` to fetch the page content, which cannot process javascript.  If the  page is using javascript to manipulate the order of the `<p>` elements, your code will never see those results.

Comment: _It is not printing twice, the first time it is new, the second time it is old_ The first two lines of the sample output are identical, so I don't understand why you would say "it is not printing twice".  It **obviously** is printing twice!  And I think it would be easier for others to understand if that didn't happen.

Comment: @JohnGordon I updated the code to make the output clearer (as to what the info is), and I updated the output sample accordingly.

Comment: @JohnGordon I mean that it isn't printing twice, it is being printed once per loop. The first time is the first time the program is seeing it, so it doesn't say 'no new update'. The second time is the second time it sees it, so it says 'no new update'.

Comment: In the sample output, can you identify the specific update text that is wrong?  i.e. the specific update text that was incorrectly found as the latest update, when it was actually the second or third?

Comment: Right now the latest update is 8:50, so the one from 8:00 is the not latest one.

Comment: So the actual problem is that the sample output contains `Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens ...`, and then `Monday: 8:00 p.m.The official ...`, and then it goes back to `Monday: 8:50 p.m.Dozens ...` ?

Comment: @John Gordon Yes. Now that I left it running for a long time, it also doesn't catch updates till like 20 minutes - even though its checking every 10 seconds.

Comment: replace the download_webpage(url) method with one that creates a browser via Selenium webdriver, goes to the URL and then waits a few seconds. Then get driver.page_source() and process that. That'll include all the data the JS brought in after the page was rendered.

Answer (score 1):

That page is being hydrated with XHR calls to an API. You can try and scrape the API directly, like in the example below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

def get_israel_news():
    headers= {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0'
    }
    r = requests.get('https://www.israelnationalnews.com/Generic/NewAPI/Item?type=0&Item=378017&preview=0')
    live_updates_df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['Content2'])
    live_updates_df['timestamp'] = live_updates_df.apply(lambda row: [x['Html'] for x in row.content][0] if len(row.content) > 1 else None, axis=1)
    live_updates_df = live_updates_df.dropna(subset='timestamp')
    live_updates_df['updates'] = live_updates_df.apply(lambda row: [x['Html'] for x in row.content][1:] if row.content[1] else None, axis=1)
    
                        
    return live_updates_df[['timestamp', 'updates']]

display(get_israel_news())
# get_israel_news().to_csv('israel_news.csv', index=False) ## you can export to csv, etc
```

Result in terminal:

```
    timestamp   updates
5   Tuesday, 1:32 p.m.:     [The IDF has identified a target moving towards Israeli territory, and fired an intercept towards it.]
6   Tuesday, 12:39 p.m.:    [Sirens sound in Be'er Sheva, Omer, and Laqiya.]
7   Tuesday, 11:47 a.m.:    [The IDF has reported that there is no threat of an aerial infiltration in the Golan Heights or the Galilee. "There is no concern of a security incident," a spokesman confirmed.]
8   Tuesday, 11:10 a.m.:    [IDF: A report was received regarding a suspected aerial infiltration in the area of the Golan Heights and the Upper Galilee. IDF soldiers are directing IDF aircraft and conducting searches in the area. Details to follow.]
9   Tuesday, 11:04 a.m.:    [Israel estimates that at least 1,500 terrorists infiltrated Israeli territory on Saturday morning.]
...     ...     ...
160     Saturday 9:00 PM:   [ sirens sounded in Rishon Lezion, Beit Dagan, Holon, Ganot, and Mishmar Hashiva.]
161     Saturday 8:00 PM    [: Air raid sirens were activated in Ness Ziona, Rehovot, Herzliya, and various other communities. Less than ten minutes later, a second barrage was fired toward Ramat Gan, Kfar Chabad, Yavne, Rishon Lezion, Tel Aviv, and other areas. Magen David Adom reported hits and injuries in Yavne, Givatayim, Bat Yam, Beit Dagan, Tel Aviv, and Rishon Lezion.]
168     It was later reported that the IAF  [continued its attacks, on targets belonging both to Hamas and to Islamic Jihad.]
170     Related articles:   [None]
173     Among the dead is Sha'ar Hanegev Regional Council Chairman  [Ofir Liebstein, , as well as the Sderot fire station chief and a firefighter.]

121 rows × 2 columns
```

Timestamps will be in order. That API, however, could do with a QA review and a code update.

See Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try modifying your <live_updates_tag> variable to:
`live_updates_tag = soup.find_all('p', class_='', text='Live Updates:')`,
This will return a list of all the elements that corespond to the parameters specified in the method. Then you'll have to loop through those (or just take the last one, depending on if the lastest update is the last on in the list).

the `.find_all` method is also beneficial, because by checking the length of the returned list, you can also check if you actually get the latest updates. If it always returns the length 1, it could be that the latest updates have different elements on the website.

NOTE:
As the comments have noted, if the live updates are being shown by javascript, then you unfortunately cannot get them with requests, you'll have to try something else such as Selenium Webdriver.
Of course, if its not processed with javascript, then it should be a matter of how you parse the content (so maybe the parameters you input to the .find method are wrong?)